# Stopword in Bahasa Indonesia

Tags: r, stop-words

How to remove stopwords for Bahasa Indonesia? If in english the R coding is...

```
some_txt6 <- tm_map(some_txt6, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: I expect that it is not available for that language.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Phil correct. it's not available in Bahasa Indonesia. But, found the answer already by  getting the external resource. The query:

install.packages("stopwords")
library(stopwords)
IndonesiaStopWords <- readLines("stoplist.txt")

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question and close it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer already by getting the external resource.

The query:
install.packages("stopwords")
library(stopwords)

IndonesiaStopWords <- readLines("stoplist.txt")